# K&R Exercise 1-9 (C)

Tags: c

> "Write a program to copy its input to
>   its output, replacing each string of
>   one or more blanks by a single blank."

I'm assuming by this he means input something like...

> **We**(blank)(blank)(blank)**go**(blank)**to**(blank)(blank)(blank)**the**(blank)**mall!**

... and output it like:

> **We**(blank)**go**(blank)**to**(blank)**the**(blank)**mall!**

This is probably easier than I'm making it out to be, but still, I can't seem to figure it out. I don't really want the code... more so *pseudo code*.

Also, how should I be looking at this? I'm pretty sure whatever program I write is going to need at least one `variable`, a `while` loop, a couple `if` statements, and will use both the `getchar()` and `putchar()` functions... but besides that I'm at a loss. I don't really have a programmers train of thought yet, so if you could give me some advice as to how I should be looking at "problems" in general that'd be awesome.

(And please don't bring up `else`, I haven't got that far in the book so right now that's out of my scope.)

Comment: +1 for good state of mind while learning.

Comment: Don't be afraid of `else`. `else` is your friend. Actually, all language constructs are your friends. Except for pointers. Be afraid of pointers.

Comment: And fear the `goto`. Just the best of their jobs know when there is really a point where using `goto` would be appropriate.

Comment: Well, you can develop a program iteratively and experimentally: Create a trivial program first, then add functionality to it. Another approach is more systematic: Think abut the different states your program encounters (in this case: which current input and which preceding input) and what you will do then. You may be interested in [state-transition diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_diagram), although more as an attitude.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Pseudo code

```
while c = getchar:
    if c is blank:
        c = getchar until c is not blank
        print blank
    print c
```

### C

You can substitute use of [`isblank`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isblank) here if you desire. It is unspecified what characters contrive blank, or what blank value is to be printed in place of others.

After many points made by Matthew in the comments below, this version, and the one containing `isblank` are the same.

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == ' ') {
        while ((c = getchar()) == ' ');
        putchar(' ');
        if (c == EOF) break;
    }
    putchar(c);
}
```

Comment: Just ask if you'd like this in C syntax.

Comment: One thing that might help: this might be a good time to learn about `ctype.h` if you don't know about it yet. `ctype.h` contains functions for determining the "type" of a `char`. That is, you can use it to see if a `char` is a letter, a number, whitespace, etc.

If it's too much to absorb now, just make a mental note for later so you don't waste time re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: It will output a garbage character (EOF) if the last character is blank.

Comment: @michael, not sure if that's aimed at me or OP, i tried to keep it simple as they're new to C

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you could put a 'while' inside a 'while' ... and could you repost the first version (the simpler one without else) too. Don't delete the new one, just have them both on their so I can compare because for now I haven't learned 'else'.

And what is 'isblank'?

Comment: In the "space is blank" version, the `c != EOF` in the inner `while` is redundant.

Comment: @Matthew: This time you are wrong :). Keep in mind that this version is highly simplified, and that EOF can be returned in later calls to getchar() in the same loop. Feel free to rip up any redundancies in the last version however.

Comment: @Matt, I don't follow.  I'm saying `while (c == ' ' && c != EOF)` can be replaced with `while (c == ' ')`.  If `c == ' '`, we already know `c != EOF`.

Comment: Oh yeah, again, good catch. I've been in python land for 8 months.

Comment: @MattJoiner sorry to resurrect this one but I went down a similar route but didn't get the program working because I didn't add the nested while loop and the program just copied the output. Looking at your answer fist off I couldn't understand how it works, but does it work because putchar() outputs a single character, in this case (' ')? Thanks

Comment: @ssbrewster: It works because the inner `while` statement burns excess spaces, before printing only a single space.

Comment: @MattJoiner - thanks for your help this has been very useful. My incorrect logic I applied was that the while loop would test the condition for each individual character and put a blank for each character, rather than recognise a continuous state. So the initial if c = blank determines the state (blank spaces) and if true the while loop recognises any number of blanks as a continuous state and putchar outputs a single blank; when a different character is read the if statement flags that the condition is not true and the program jumps to putchar(c)?

Answer (score 24):

Look at your program as a machine that moves between different states as it iterates over the input.

It reads the input one character at a time. If it sees anything other than a blank, it just prints the character it sees. If it sees a blank, it shifts to a different state. In that state, it prints one blank, and then *doesn't* print blanks if it sees them. Then, it continues reading the input, but ignores all blanks it sees--until it hits a character that isn't a blank, at which point it shifts back to the first state.

(This concept is called a *finite state machine*, by the way, and a lot of theoretical computer science work has gone into what they can and can't do. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) can tell you more, though in perhaps more complicated detail than you're looking for. ;))

Comment: @MW2000: this is how regular expressions matchers work. They build a specific finite state machine from the pattern you specify. If you don't know what a regex is just check it out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Answer (score 5):

Since relational operators in C produce integer values 1 or 0 (as explained earlier in the book), the logical expression "current character non-blank or previous character non-blank" can be simulated with integer arithmetic resulting in a shorter (if somewhat cryptic) code:

```
int c, p = EOF;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if ((c != ' ') + (p != ' ') > 0) putchar(c);
    p = c;
}
```

Variable `p` is initialized with `EOF` so that it has a valid non-blank value during the very first comparison.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I got:

```
while ch = getchar()
   if ch != ' '
      putchar(ch)
   if ch == ' '
      if last_seen_ch != ch
         putchar(ch)
   last_seen_ch = ch
```

Comment: This is the easiest algorithm here IMO. Bravo!

Comment: replace `if ch == ' '` by `else`, since it can only be space because of the inverse condition above

Answer (score 3):

Same explanation with Matt Joiner's, but this code does not use `break`.

```
int c;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (c == ' ') /* find a blank */
    {
        putchar(' '); /* print the first blank */
        while ((c = getchar()) == ' ') /* look for succeeding blanks then… */
            ; /* do nothing */
    }

    if (c != EOF) /* We might get an EOF from the inner while-loop above */
        putchar(c);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I worked really hard at finding a solution that used only the material that has already been covered in the first part of the first chapter of the book.  Here is my result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Write a            program         to copy its input to       its output, replacing             each string of one         or more blanks by a single blank. */

main()
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if (c == ' '){
            putchar(c);
            while ((c = getchar()) == ' ')
                ;
        }
        if(c != ' ')
            putchar(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: The second if statement can be replaced by an 'else', since if the first condition if false, it follows that c != ' ' is true.

Comment: No, it can't for a subtle reason: the getchar() call in the inner while loop will have consumed the first non-blank character when testing the loop condition for the last time.  If you don't check c before falling back to the outer while loop, you'll loose the first character after your consecutive blanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I think of the algorithm of this exercise, in pseudo-code:

```
define ch and bl (where bl is initially defined to be 0)

while ch is = to getchar() which is not = to end of file  
do the following:  
      if ch is = to blank and bl is = 0  
          --> output ch and assign the value 1 to bl  
      else --> if ch is = to blank and bl is = 1  
          --> do nothing  
      else --> output ch and assign the value 0 to bl
```

Example implementation in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main() {

   long ch,bl=0;

   while ((ch=getchar()) != EOF)
   {
       if (ch == ' ' && bl == 0)
       {
           putchar(ch);
           bl=1;
       } else if (ch == ' ' && bl == 1) {
           // no-op
       } else {
           putchar(ch);
           bl=0;
       }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've raised an edit review of your answer, tidying up the formatting and wording.  Don't fear taking your time to answer questions, remember anyone (often those whom English is not their first language) will be reading this - possibly in 5 years' time.  Try to keep it as readable as possible, be informative.  Welcome to StackOverflow... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this and seems to be working.

```
 # include <stdio.h>
 int main ()
{

int c,lastc;
lastc=0;
while ((c=getchar()) != EOF)
    if (((c==' ')+ (lastc==' '))<2)
        putchar(c), lastc=c;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c;
    while( (c = getchar( )) != EOF )
    {           
        if (c == ' ') 
        {
            while ((c = getchar()) == ' ');
            putchar(' ');
            putchar(c);
        }
        else 
            putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int c, numBlank=0 ;
    while((c= getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        if(c ==' ')
    {
        numBlank ++;
        if(numBlank <2)
        {
        printf("character is:%c\n",c);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("character is:%c\n",c);
        numBlank =0;
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First declare two variables character and last_character as integers.when you have not reach the end of the file( while(character=getchar() != EOF ) do this;
1. If character != ' ' then
      print character
      last_character = character
2. If character == ' '
     if last_character ==' '
     last character = character
   else print character

Answer (score 1):

Using the constraints of not using else or and operators. This code only prints a blank when the blank variable is equal to 1 and the only way to reset the counter is by typing something other than a blank. Hope this helps:

## include

/* Write a program that replaces strings of blanks with a single blank */

void main(){
    int c, bl;

```
bl = 0;

while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    if(c == ' '){
        ++bl;
        if(bl == 1){
            putchar(' ');
        }
    }
    if(c != ' '){
        putchar(c);
        bl = 0;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Many others have already used the last character logic in their code, but perhaps the following version is easier to read:

```
int c, prevchar;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (!(c == ' ' && prevchar == ' ')) {
        putchar(c);
        prevchar = c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int input, last = EOF;
    while ((input = getchar()) != EOF) {
       if (input == ' ' && last == ' ') continue;
       last = input; 
       putchar(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Next time don't just post your code here, give a little explanation about it

Comment: @guest The Op is new so we must give him explanation how to get through

Answer (score 0):

I am at the same point in the book. and my solution goes with making a count++ if blank is found and making the count back to zero if anything other than blank is found.

For if statement I put another another check to check value of count (if zero) and then print.

Though at this point of learning I shouldn't be concern about efficiency of two methods but which one is efficient a.) Accepted solution here with while inside while or b.) the one I suggested above.

My code goes like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>


main()
{
    int count=0,c;
    for( ; (c=getchar())!=EOF; )
    {
        if(c==' ')
        {
            if(count==0)
            {
                putchar(c);
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(c!=' ')
        {
            putchar(c);
            count=0;
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1.Count the number of blanks.
2.Replace the counted number of blanks by a single one.
3.Print the characters one by one.

<code>
main()
{
    int c, count;
    count = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == ' ')
        {
            count++;
            if (count > 1) 
            {
                putchar ('\b');
                putchar (' ');
            }
            else putchar (' ');
        }
        else 
        {
            putchar (c);
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    return;
}
</code>
```

Comment: I'm sorry for lack of explanation because I'm novice in english learning and in C programming too...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>   
main()
{
    int CurrentChar, LastChar;
    LastChar = '1';
    while ((CurrentChar = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (CurrentChar != ' ')
        {
            putchar(CurrentChar);
            LastChar = '1';
        }
        else
        {
            if (LastChar != ' ')
            {
                putchar(CurrentChar);               
                LastChar = ' ';
            }                   
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a way to make it easier for the new people are stuck on this book
(by not knowing any thing then what brought up until page 22 in K&R).

*credits to @Michael , @Mat and @Matthew to help me to understand*

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
 int c;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) /* state of "an input is not EOF" (1) */ 
 {
        if (c == ' ') /* "blank has found" -> change the rule now */
        {
          while ((c = getchar ()) == ' '); /* as long you see blanks just print for it a blank until rule is broken (2) */
          putchar(' ');
        }
   putchar(c); /* either state (2) was broken or in state (1) no blanks has been found */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
        long c;
        long nb = 0;
        while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
                if(c == ' ' || c == '\t') {
                        ++nb;
                } else {
                        if(nb > 0) {
                                putchar(' ');
                                nb = 0;
                        }

                        putchar(c);
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this using only while loops and if statements, the trick is to add a variable which remembers the previous character.

```
Loop, reading one character at a time, until EOF:
    If the current character IS NOT a space:
        Output current character

    If the current character IS a space:
        If the previous character WAS NOT a space:
            Output a space

    Set previous character to current character
```

In C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c, p;

    p = EOF;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != ' ')
            putchar(c);

        if (c == ' ')
            if (p != ' ')
                putchar(' ');

        p = c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also starting out with the K&R textbook, and I came up with a solution that uses only the material which had been covered up until that point.

How it works:

First, set some counter 'blanks' to zero. This is used for counting blanks.

If a blank is found, increase the counter 'blanks' by one.

If a blank is not found, then first do a sub-test: is the counter 'blanks' equal or bigger than 1? If yes, then first, print a blank and after that, set the counter 'blanks' back to zero.

After this subtest is done, go back and putchar whatever character was not found to be a blank.

The idea is, before putcharing a non-blank character, first do a test to see, if some blank(s) were counted before. If there were blanks before, print a single blank first and then reset the counter of blanks. That way, the counter is zero again for the next round of blank(s). If the first character on the line is not a blank, the counter couldn't have increased, hence no blank is printed.

One warning, I haven't gone very far into the book, so I'm not familiar with the syntax yet, so it's possible that the {} braces might be written in different places, but my example is working fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Copy input to output, replacing each string of one or more blanks by a single blank. */

main()
{
    int c, blanks;

    blanks = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c != ' ') {
            if (blanks >= 1)
                printf(" ");
                blanks = 0;
            putchar(c); }
        if (c == ' ')
            ++blanks;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like many other people, I am studying this book as well and found this question very interesting.

I have come up with a piece of code that only uses what has been explained before the exercice (as I am not consulting any other resource but just playing with the code).

There is a `while` loop to parse the text and one `if` to compare the current character to the previous one.
Are there any edge cases where this code would not work ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {

    // c    current character
    // pc   previous character
    int c, pc;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        // A truthy evaluation implies 1 
        // (learned from chapter 1, exercice 6)
        // Avoid writing a space when 
        //  - the previous character is a space (+1)
        //  AND
        //  - the current character is a space (+1)
        // All the other combinations return an int < 2
        if ((pc == ' ') + (pc == c) < 2) {
            putchar(c);
        }
        // update previous character
        pc = c;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(nb = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF;)
{
    if(c == ' ')
       nb++;
    if( nb == 0 || nb == 1 )
       putchar(c);
    if(c != ' '  &&  nb >1)
       putchar(c);
    if(c != ' ')
       nb = 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, I am currently in the same spot you were years ago.

I used only the syntax taught until this point in the books and it reduces the multiple spaces into one space only as required.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int c
    int blanks = 0; // spaces counter
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {        
        if (c == ' ') { // if the character is a blank
            while((c = getchar()) == ' ') { //check the next char and count blanks

                blanks++;

                // if(c == EOF){
                // break;
                // }
            }            
            if (blanks >= 0) { // comparing to zero to accommodate the single space case, 
                               // otherwise ut removed the single space between chars
                putchar(' '); // print single space in all cases                    
            }

        }
        putchar(c); //print the next char and repeat        
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I removed the break part as it was not introduced yet in the book,hope this help new comers like me :)

Comment: Besides having been written by you, how is this code (ie: answer) any different than the existing answers? When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using only the techniques described so far in [K&R's C](http://alvand.basu.ac.ir/%7Edezfoulian/files/Programming/Prentice%20Hall%20-%20The%20C%20Programming%20Language-%20Brian%20W.%20Kernighan,%20Dennis%20M.%20Ritchie,%202nd%20ed.,%20ISBN%20.pdf). In addition to using a variable to achieve a [finite state change](https://youtu.be/hJIST1cEf6A) for distinguishing the first blank space from successive blank spaces, I've also added a variable to count blank spaces along with a print statement to verify the total number. This helped me to wrap my head around `getchar()` and `putchar()` a little better - as well as the scope of the while loop within main().

```
// Exercise 1-9. Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing
//               each string of one or more blanks by a single blank.

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int blank_state;
    int c;
    int blank_count;

    printf("Replace one or more blanks with a single blank.\n");
    printf("Use ctrl+d to insert an EOF after typing ENTER.\n\n");

    blank_state = 0;
    blank_count = 0;
    while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF )
    {
        if (c == ' ')
        {
            ++blank_count;
            if (blank_state == 0)
            {
                blank_state = 1;
                putchar(c);
            }
        }
        if (c != ' ')
        {
            blank_state = 0;
            putchar(c);
        }
    }

    printf("Total number of blanks: %d\n", blank_count);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
 int c, flag=0;

   while((c=getchar()) != EOF){

      if(c == ' '){
         if(flag == 0){
            flag=1;
            putchar(c);
        }
    }else{
        flag=0;
        putchar(c);
     }

   }

  return 0;

}
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*a program that copies its input to its output, replacing each string of one or more blanks by a single blank*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    double c;
    char blank = ' ';

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if(c == ' ')                                
            {
            putchar(c);                             

                while(( c = getchar() )== ' ')      

                    {
                    if(c != ' ')                    
                    break;
                    }
            }




        if(c == '\t')                               
            {
                putchar(blank);                     
                    while((c = getchar()) == '\t')  

                    {
                    if(c != '\t')                   
                    break;
                    }
            }

    putchar(c);                                     
    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// K & R Exercise 1.9
// hoping to do this with as few lines as possible 

int c = 0, lastchar = 0;
c = getchar();
while (c != EOF) {
  if (lastchar != ' ' || c != ' ') putchar(c);
  lastchar=c;
  c=getchar();
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Considering what's asked in the question, I have also made sure that the program runs smooth in case of various tabs, spaces as well as when they're clubbed together to form various combinations!
Here's my code,

```
int c, flag = 1;
    printf("Enter the character!\n");
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == ' '||c == '\t') {
        c=getchar();
        while(c == ' '|| c == '\t')
               {
                   c = getchar();
               }
        putchar(' ');
        if (c == EOF) break;
    }
    putchar(c);
}
```

Feel free to run all test cases using various combinations of spaces and tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Solution1: as per topics covered in the k&R book:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
       if  (c == ' ') 
       {while ( getchar() == ' ' )
        ;  // ... we take no action
        }

        putchar(c);

    }

return 0;
}
```

Solution2 : using program states:

```
int main()
{
    int c, nblanks = 0 ;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)  
{
   if (c != ' ')
       { putchar(c);
         nblanks = 0;}

   else if (c==' ' && nblanks == 0) // change of state
            {putchar(c);
             nblanks++;}
}
return 0;
}
```

Solution3 : based on last seen char

```
int main()
{
int c, lastc = 0;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if ( c != ' ')
        {putchar(c);}


        if (c == ' ')
        {
            if (c==lastc)
                ;
            else putchar(c);

        }

        lastc = c;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I approached it;

```
make input loop
check if the character is \t; if it is, then change the value of that character to four blanks
check if the character is a blank
make a while loop that runs as long as the next character (another getchar) is a blank
if the statement above is still running, set a state variable to 1
after the loop; check if the state is 1; if it is, then set the current character to a single blank
print the remaining inputs
```

*Scroll down for code*
















Code:

```c
/* Exercise 1-9 */
#include <stdio.h>

/* Program to replace 2 or more blanks in input with a single blank */
int main() {
    int c;
    int blank_state;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        blank_state = 0;
        if (c == '\t')
            c = '    ';
        if (c == ' ') {
            while((c = getchar()) == ' ')
                blank_state = 1;
        }

        if (blank_state == 1)
            c = ' ';
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution keeps track of last read character in `p`. After reading the current character it does a simple check before the output:

- If the last read character was a blank and current character is also a blank, which means we have consecutive blanks, it does nothing.
- Else it just prints the current character.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
  int c;
  int p;
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF){ 
    if(p==' ' &&  c==' ');
    else putchar(c);
    p = c;
  }
}
```